# How to access wsdl in grails - 400 status code return

Tags: java, web-services, grails, soap, wsdl

I want to send the data to person object. How to do it with PostMethod.

```
    def payload ='<person><nationalId>'+1234567+'</nationalId></person>'
    def method = new PostMethod(url)
    def client = new HttpClient()
    payload = payload.trim()
    method.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml")
    method.addRequestHeader("Accept","text/xml,application/xml;q=0.9")

    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials('simple', 'simple');
    client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,8080, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "digest"),credentials);

    method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(payload))
    def statusCode = client.executeMethod(method)
    println "STATUS CODE : ${statusCode}"
    def resultsString = method.getResponseBodyAsString()
    method.releaseConnection()
    println resultsString
```

I tried above coding. How to set password and username and password digest also. For that i think status code 400 is coming.Please notify where i made mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [REST Client Builder Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder). See docs and I guess, you'll find more convenient way to send request

Comment: Mr.cat Thanks for your help. using this can i call wsdl and pass parameter?

Comment: Never used in such case. Try